# Getting name error: name 'IMGS' is not defined, thought i have defined it inside the class

Tags: python, python-3.x, nameerror

In the bird class, variable IMGS is defined but i'm getting Name error, should that be declared as a global variable.

```
**BIRD_IMGS** = [pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs", "bird1.png"))), pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs", "bird2.png"))), pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs", "bird3.png")))]

class Bird:
    **IMGS** = BIRD_IMGS
    MAX_ROTATION = 25
    ROT_VEL = 20
    ANIMATION_TIME = 5

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.tilt = 0
        self.tick_count = 0
        self.vel = 0
        self.height = self.y
        self.img_count = 0
        self.img = self.IMGS[0]

    def draw (self, win):
        self.img_count += 1
```

NameError: name 'IMGS' is not defined

```
    # to make the wing flapping animation
        if self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME:
            self.img = IMGS[0]
        elif self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME*2:
            self.img = IMGS[1]
        elif self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME*3:
            self.img = IMGS[2]
        elif self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME*4:
            self.img = IMGS[1]
        elif self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME*4 + 1:
            self.img = IMGS[0]
```

main()

Answer (score 2):

Names defined at the top level of a `class` block become class attributes (attributes of the "class" object, shared by all instances of the class) - they are not exposed in the "global" module namespace. IOW, you have to go thru the class or an instance of it to access them, ie:

```
print(Bird.IMGS)
b = Bird()
print(b.IMGS)
print(b.IMGS is Bird.IMGS)
```

And since Python has no implicit `this` pointer, within your methods, you have to use the current instance (`self`) to access this attribute:

```
if self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME:
    self.img = self.IMGS[0]
```